# How do I install directx 11 on ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: games, steam

I'm trying to play steam games on my fresh install of ubuntu, and it keeps saying I need directx 11 installed. All of the tutorials on google don't work or are out of date and I'm still getting the same error, any help?

Comment: It would surely be helpful to know what game you're trying to install/run and whether it's the Windows or Linux version of the game (or if you're using Proton, Wine -- and what version -- or PlayOnLinux to run a Windows game).  DirectX is generally a Windows accelerator...

Comment: Its every game I am able to download from steam, so it isn't one particular game, and Wine is default, but I have playonlinux as well and I have the same error. I am familiar with what directx is, I have an Asus R500vm with a nvidia Geforce GT 2gb card. It has been some time since I've used linux full time, and I am at a loss as to what to do here

Comment: My experience is that games are especially tricky to get working in Wine, whether directly or via PlayOnLinux.  One I play regularly, *There*, has about a dozen steps to go through and even then only works on some versions of Wine (and one function quit two years ago and I haven't found anyone who can tell me how to restore it).